# Let $F=K(u)$ where $u$ is transcendental over $K$, prove that it is algebraic over $E$, where $K \subset E \subseteq F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $F=K(u)$ where $u$ is transcendental over $K$. Prove that it is algebraic over $E$, where $K \subset E \subseteq F$.

The method I tried for the above question was as follows: Choose $v \in E/K$ then $$v=\frac{f(u)}{g(u)} \quad , \quad f(x),g(x) \in K[x] \subset E[x]$$ Then we have that $f(u)=vg(u)$. Define $p(x) \in E[x]$ by $p(x)=f(x)-vg(x)$ so that $p(u)=0$ and hence, $u$ is algebraic over $E$. I think this is correct but I just want to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: It's more or less correct. To be careful, you would also have to verify that $p(x)$ is not identically zero.

Comment: Thanks, $p$ wouldn't be identically zero as that would give a contradiction

Comment: how do we show that p is not identically zero?

Comment: If $p$ were identically zero, then in particular  $p(0) = 0$. If $g (0) \neq 0$ then $f(0), g (0) \in F $ and we can deduce that $v = \frac{f (0)}{g (0)} $. Since $F $ is a field, $v \in F $, contradicting our choice of $v$. If $g (0) = 0$ then $0=p (0)=f (0)-vg (0) = f (0) $ hence we can divide the numerator and denominator of $v$ by $u $. Continuing the same argument if necessary, we eventually arrive at polynomials $f', g' \in F [u]$ with $g'(0) \neq 0$ and $v = \frac {f'(0)}{g'(0)}$, so that $v \in F $, again a contradiction.